# Deafult APIs for objects in Salesforce

Tags: c#

Integrated Salesforce API into an ASP.Net form. And for that, I have created an Apex class, generated the WSDL and consumed it in the form. When user enters an emailid in the form and clicks on submit, it gets the related address from `Lead` object in salesforce. This is working fine.

**Apex class:**

```
global class getLeadInfo {

  WebService static Lead getLeadAddressByEmail(string LeadEmail) {
    Lead c = [SELECT Street, City, State, PostalCode from Lead WHERE Email = :LeadEmail];
    Lead l = new Lead(Street = c.Street, City = c.City, State = c.State);    
   return l;
  }
}
```

Here is what I would like to do.

1. Just like `Lead`, get all data from `Accounts` object now. But I want to do all the coding only in the ASP form and not at the Force.com console. Is this possible.
2. Is there a default API for every salesforce object (`Lead`, `Accounts`, `campaigns`) with which we can do CRUD.

The articles I have checked arent so helful for a beginner. There is lot of difference in the current Interface and the steps mentioned(even in the offcial docs).

Comment: Have you checked Salesforce Metada API? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/

Comment: From what I understand, metadata is only for managing the model and not the data. To CRUD data I should only use soap or rest api. Is that right? If yes, could you help me with any pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the [REST API](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_rest.pdf) is what you are looking for.

A few advantages:

- You don't need to be downloading WSDLs.
- You can create a generic query on the ASP side for queries on multiple   objects.
- No coding on the salesforce side.